# AngularJS controller $scope reserved keyword?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

I am a newbie to Angular, I came across [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gWz4K/403/) which explains how nested controller works. When I rename $scope to something else say $abc and it doesn't work, does it mean that $scope is a reserved keyword in angularJS?

```
function CarController($scope) {

    $scope.name = 'Car';
    $scope.type = 'Car';

}

function BMWController($scope) {

    $scope.name = 'BMW';

}

function BMWMotorcycleController($scope) {

    $scope.name = 'BMWMotorade';
    $scope.type = 'Motorcycle';

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Effectively, yes. It's not a reserved word in the sense that e.g. `if` and `while` are but AngularJS gives it meaning. In your example Angular parses the string representation of the function and uses the named parameters to determine what to "inject" into the function when it calls it.

In this case you're injecting the `$scope` service.

Comment: So AngularJS decides what to feed into the controller function by parsing the arguments list. Now that's quite unordinary but innovative at the same time! It's like a two-way function.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a reserved keyword, it's a specific dependency. You can ask all sorts of dependencies. For example, you can define a service and call it "$abc", and then inject that service into your controller. For more info:

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di

Answer (score 0):

Your concept will be more clear by watching following video - 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NnB2NBtoeAY&list=PLP6DbQBkn9ymGQh2qpk9ImLHdSH5T7yw7&index=26
Hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

I saw this on a AngularJS tut on their website:

> This scope is a prototypical descendant of the root scope that was
>   created when the application was defined.